# How to tell which segment user is interacting with in dynamic road building system?

Tags: unity, c#

Im prototyping dynamic road building system as seen in most city builder games. I gather the points from user input (red dots) and programmatically generate mesh.

It's currently one big mesh, seems like a good default rendering performance wise.

[image]

---

Starting a new road/creating intersection from already existing road is a very important feature. Everything is pretty straight forward except how to know which segment user is hovering, clicking.

Options:

- split segments into separate gameobjects and attach collider to each
- use single big mesh and create empty gameobjects for colliders only

**Is there a better way besides these two?** That would be a lot of colliders if you consider the scale of city builders. I suspect there's a smarter way..

*Note:* on the other hand, if user adds new intersections, updating a huge mesh could be a problem. If I split meshes into reasonable chuncks, I could localize updates to only affected meshes.

---

Simplified data structure:

```
public class Road {
    public List<Segment> segments;
}

public class Segment {
    public Vector3 start;
    public Vector3 end;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add another property to the Segment, referring to its index on the road's list.

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter Im not sure how that would help me to get the segment user is hovering/clicking in more efficient way than the ones I listed above. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a large, procedurally generated mesh collider for your whole road network and still detect on which segment the user clicked.

Use [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to detect the road mesh collider under the mouse cursor. The [`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) structure has a property [`.triangleIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html) which contains the number of the triangle where the hit occurred.

So all you need to do is keep a lookup table during your mesh generation which remembers which triangle of your procedurally generated mesh belongs to which logical road segment.

However, you might still want to consider to split your road network into multiple meshes for performance reasons. When the whole road network of the whole city is one big <s>mess</s> mesh, then the Unity rendering engine can't apply frustum culling to ignore the off-screen parts of it. You can't even use LOD groups, because the whole object needs to be rendered in the same level of detail. I also see problems with constantly rebuilding the whole mesh when the player makes changes to the road network.

There are different approaches you could take here, like handling all the roads in rectangular areas as game objects or handling each road from intersection to intersection as one game object. The best approach depends on your game.

Comment: One more quick question: how would you implement lookup table? `List<List<int>>` would cause a lot of looping each frame if every index is stored, `List<Vector2>` would also work for storing only ranges. or dictionary? Can't be too much data, need to keep it around.

Comment: @Sir I would turn `Segment` into a class (so it gets stored by reference and not by value) and then create an array of segments. The array index is the number of the triangle. So if you want to know which segment triangle 1317 belongs to, you would use `segmentLookupTable[1317]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop on all the segments, Find the segment that is closest to the cursor position and get the exact location that you need from there.

As for keeping track of which segments you need to update\regenerate, just add a flag to the segment class that represents if the segment is generated or needs to be regenerated\update and integrate it with your mesh generation function. (you will probably need to separate the road mesh to chunks tho)